# Don't change HTML DOM After Using JQuery Load() Function

Tags: jquery, ajax

There is an HTML Page that using the `Ajax Load() function` loads another HTML files into current HTML document(into a specified element). when clicking on `Links` the other HTML pages loads as proper. The code loaded using load() cause addition to DOM but the source code doesn't not change. You can see the changed html in page but not in source.

Do DOM didn't manipulate when using `JQuery Load() function`?

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery Learning</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="..//jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#newslinks a').click(function() {
                var url=$(this).attr('href');
                $('#headlines').load(url+' #newsItem');
                return false;
        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul id='newslinks'>
        <li><a href='today.html'>Today's News</a></li>
        <li><a href='yesterday.html'>Yesterday's News</a></li>
        <li><a href='week.html'>Last Week's News</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id='headlines'>
        <h3>This is headlines of News</h3>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is raised when looking onto HTML page source using Firebug
>   after load another HTML page, the page source didn't change!

The code loaded using `load()` cause addition to `DOM` but the source code doesn't not change. You can see the changed `html` in page but not in source.